# UnsupportedOperationException - OnCheckedChanged

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to select and remove categories in a RecyclerView but i got UnsupportedOperationException with some specific phone brands(Android version 8 or 9).

My code:

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->

        if (isChecked){
            mListener.onItemSelected(position,true)  //CategoryAdapter.kt:42
            mSelectedItems.add(position)
        }else{
            mListener.onItemSelected(position,false)
            mSelectedItems.remove(position)
        }
        //notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
//
//

private var categoriesDefault = mutableListOf<String>()

override fun onItemSelected(position: Int, isSelected: Boolean) {
    if (isSelected){
        categoriesDefault.add(categoriesValues[position]) //CategoryFragment.kt:19
    }else{
        categoriesDefault.remove(categoriesValues[position])
    }

    tinyDB.categories = categoriesDefault
}
```

Fatal error log:

```
#0. Crashed: main
   at java.util.AbstractList.add + 148(AbstractList.java:148)
   at java.util.AbstractList.add + 108(AbstractList.java:108)
   at com.blarma.high5.aui.base.wordsetting.CategoryFragment.onItemSelected + 19(CategoryFragment.kt:19)
   at com.blarma.high5.aui.base.wordsetting.CategoryAdapter$onBindViewHolder$1.onCheckedChanged + 42(CategoryAdapter.kt:42)
   at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked + 182(CompoundButton.java:182)
   at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle + 136(CompoundButton.java:136)
   at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick + 141(CompoundButton.java:141)
   at android.view.View.performClickInternal + 7305(View.java:7305)
   at android.view.View.access$3200 + 846(View.java:846)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run + 27787(View.java:27787)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 873(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 214(Looper.java:214)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7078(ActivityThread.java:7078)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 493(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 964(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Edit: more logs here
I do not know where the problem is but hopefully someone can figure it out. And I can not post more due to "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." error.

```
#1. Answers Events Handler1
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$ + 2137(Thread.java:2137)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park + 358(Unsafe.java:358)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos + 230(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos + 2101(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2101)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take + 1132(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1132)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take + 849(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:849)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask + 1092(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1152(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 641(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun + 75(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run + 30(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run + 764(Thread.java:764)

#2. Crashlytics Exception Handler1
       at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace + 1538(Thread.java:1538)
       at java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces + 1588(Thread.java:1588)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.writeSessionEvent + 1340(CrashlyticsController.java:1340)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.writeFatal + 1027(CrashlyticsController.java:1027)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.access$500 + 69(CrashlyticsController.java:69)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$7.call + 328(CrashlyticsController.java:328)
       at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController$7.call + 321(CrashlyticsController.java:321)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run + 266(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1167(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 641(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun + 75(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
       at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run + 30(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
       at java.lang.Thread.run + 764(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: what is mSelectedItems?

Comment: mSelectedItems:ArrayList<Int>

Comment: Maybe you are using an implementation of an immutable list and hence the error while adding or removing items.

Comment: @Froyo private var categoriesDefault = mutableListOf<String>() that seems mutable

Comment: @EmmaAlden is there more stacktrace?

Comment: Since `categoriesDefault` is a variable, is it being reassigned in the code somewhere?

Comment: @Froyo I edited logs. Only once i assig categoriesDefault = tinyDB.categories in onCreateView.

Comment: @EmmaAlden tinyDB.categories could return an immutable list. Please check that. Better to use `categoriesDefault = tinyDB.categories.toMutableList()` or `categoriesDefault.addAll(tinyDB.categories)`. I am assuming tinyDb.categories is a syntactic sugar and the implementation may return an immutable list.

Comment: @Froyo it returns List<String>. Probably it causes the error. Thank you so much for your help.